# Using xargs and variables

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables

Hey I have a question.

This is the command that I'm using (at the place of `echo $file` is a different command. I simplified it):

`find /home/cas/plex-media/series/ -type f -name "*" ! -name "*.srt" -print0 | sort | xargs -0 -n1 -I{} file={} && echo $file`

It says that `file={}` isn't a command, which is true because it is a variable. I need to set that variable to one line of the output each time, just as xargs does with a command. But I need it to fill the variable and then run that command with that variable for each line of the ouput of sort.

Example:

As input (aka ouput of sort):

```
/home/cas/plex-media/series/Pokémon/Season 1/Pokémon - S01E01 - Pokémon - I Choose You!.mp4
/home/cas/plex-media/series/Pokémon/Season 1/Pokémon - S01E02 - Pokémon Emergency.mp4
/home/cas/plex-media/series/Pokémon/Season 1/Pokémon - S01E03 - Ash Catches a Pokémon.mp4
```

How I want it to be executed every time by xargs:

```
file=/home/cas/plex-media/series/Pokémon/Season 1/Pokémon - S01E01 - Pokémon - I Choose You!.mp4 && echo /home/cas/plex-media/series/Pokémon/Season 1/Pokémon - S01E01 - Pokémon - I Choose You!.mp4
file=/home/cas/plex-media/series/Pokémon/Season 1/Pokémon - S01E02 - Pokémon Emergency.mp4 && echo /home/cas/plex-media/series/Pokémon/Season 1/Pokémon - S01E02 - Pokémon Emergency.mp4
file=/home/cas/plex-media/series/Pokémon/Season 1/Pokémon - S01E03 - Ash Catches a Pokémon.mp4 && echo /home/cas/plex-media/series/Pokémon/Season 1/Pokémon - S01E03 - Ash Catches a Pokémon.mp4
```

I can't just do `echo {}` as I have multiple places is my command where `{}` needs to be filled in and I have quite alot of `command {} $(other command {})`. So I replaced all those places where the output of sort needs to go with the variable `$file`. Because then xargs only needs to change the variable once and run the command. Then change the variable and run the command again etc etc.

I hope that you understand my problem and what my goal is. Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that if you're using `-print0` and `xargs -0` you will need to use null delimiting in the sort as well i.e. `sort -z`

Comment: ,,, also note that `-name "*"` is redundant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `xargs` with `sh -c` (or`bash -c` if needed):

```
find ...  -print0 |  sort -z | xargs -0 -n1 -I{} sh -c 'file=$1; echo "$file";' xargs-sh {}
```

---

If you don't need the `sort` step, better avoid `xargs` and use `find -exec` :

```
find /home/cas/plex-media/series/ -type f ! -name "*.srt" \
  -exec sh -c 'file=$1; echo "$file";' find-sh {} \;
```

---

For why we need this strange notation `sh -c '...' sh {}` , please see [Is it possible to use `find -exec sh -c` safely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008/is-it-possible-to-use-find-exec-sh-c-safely)

Comment: So I need to do `find ... \ -exec sh -c 'file=$1; command;' find-sh {} \;`? Why is it `file=$1` and not `file={}`? And are the `'` needed, as I have alot of `'` and `"` and it will mess up all the commands, or will it not mess them up?

Comment: You pass the `{}` as regular argument to the `sh` script. It is the only safe way to do so, if you put `{}` directly in your script, you get a code injection vulnerability.

Comment: I added a link that explain that very well.

Comment: I've been banging my head for hours. My problem was getting the variable to expand in the single quotes. Using double quotes and `xargs` would print blank if trying to `echo` the variable in say `ls . | xargs -I {} sh -c "p=test; echo $p {}"`. `xargs-sh` fixes everything and allows single quote usage with variable expansion, but what is it and where did you find it?!